# MYSQL DELETE PDO : how I know if row was deleted?

Tags: php

I want to know if there is a better way to find if a row was deleted using PDO.
What am I doing now is to read first from database and then delete. If read operation returns content I display success message and if not I display data not fount message.

This is my code:

```
$find_it = 0;
    $content = $cancel_db->select_all_general("SELECT * FROM dm_bookings WHERE id = '$c_reference' AND email = '$c_email'");
    foreach ($content as $row){
        $find_it = 1;
    }
    $cancel_db->insert_update_delete_general_no_m("DELETE FROM dm_bookings WHERE id = '$c_reference' AND email = '$c_email'");
    if($find_it == 1) {
        $div_class = "alert-success";
        $mesaj = "<br />Booking deleted!<br /><br />";
    } else {
        $div_class = "alert-danger";
        $mesaj = "<br /Booking not finded!<br /><br />";
    }
```

Is there a way to improve this?
Thanks.

Comment: You should look into using parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that.

Comment: you are not using PDO but some custom slution

Comment: Your Common Sense is right ... my question was already answered ... didnt see that answer. sorry.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have a look at [PDO::exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php), first example is what you are looking for :

```
/* Delete all rows from the FRUIT table */
$count = $dbh->exec("DELETE FROM fruit");

/* Return number of rows that were deleted */
print("Deleted $count rows.\n");
```

Comment: Please include the actual solution in the answer and only add the link as a reference. If not, this answer won't be very helpful for future visitors if the link would be off-line, even temporary.

Comment: Thanks! Now my code is lighter and more efficient.

Comment: PDO::exec doesn't support prepared statements and hence shouldn't  be used

Answer (score 0):

Using `PDO` in PHP gives you the ability to use `rowCount();` which returns a count of all rows affects by the last query.

Something like the code below would be able to check to see if it was deleted.

```
<?php

/* This will only check if a total of 1 was deletd, however, to change this replace == to > */
if($pdo->rowCount() == 1){
   /* Row Deleted */
} else {
   /* Row was not deleted */
}

?>
```